# Azure Search: rotationFromOriginal not properly populated

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

As I am reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios), *"when the imageAction is set to generateNormalizedImages, the new normalized_images field will contain an array of images. Each image is a complex type"* which should contain a very important field for my scenario (rotationFromOriginal).

I noticed that, even if Azure Search perfectly accomplish the rotation of the images, this property will always be 0 (unlike other fields as originalWidth, which are correctly populated).

Do you know why I have this issue? Am I the only one?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the value of `rotationFromOriginal` was in `normalized_images` and it was **as an input**, so it must be populated at first.

And use the parameters in `normalized_images` json file to rotation and process image. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios#image-related-skills).

Comment: Ok then why I can access other infos but not the rotationFromOriginal one?

Comment: The `rotationFromOriginal` value is set by you. And could you tell me how do you get the `rotationFromOriginal`?